# How to scroll to the top of a div using either scrollTop or scrollTo

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 4 modals on a page. If I open one scroll to the bottom, close it, and reopen it, it puts me where I scrolled to last in the modal. This happens with every modal so if I scroll to the bottom of the first modal, close it and then open up the 3rd modal it will put me to the bottom of the modal.

I am trying to create a javascript funciton which scrolls the modal to the top onclick of the element which opens up the modal.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated as I seem to not be able to find any solutions anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Answer (score 1):

Use the element's `.scroll()` function. `document.getElementById("element-id").scroll(0,0);`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this example helps you.
In this example, we start from the top to a div down there. Then we go back to another div at the top.

It's simple. Get the div id and then its position on the screen with offsetTop. This value is then passed to the top option in window.scroll.

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var myDiv2 = document.getElementById("myDiv2");

function scrollMe(){
  scrollToMyDiv(myDiv);
}
function scrollMe2(){
  scrollToMyDiv(myDiv);
}
function scrollToMyDiv(element) {
  window.scroll({
    top: element.offsetTop,
    left: 0,    
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="scrollMe()">scroll now</a>

<div id="myDiv2">
    <p>div 2</p>
</div>
<div style="height:200vh;background-color:lime;"></div>

<div id="myDiv" style="background-color:red">
  <p><a onclick="scrollMe2()" href="#">scroll to div 2</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Felipe, I do understand this example and it was helpful, Thank you but I am essentially trying to use window.scrollTo or window.scrollBy on a specific div rather than the window itself. Would you have any ideas on how to do this. No worries if you don't know, thank you for the help so far.

Comment: Let's try to understand. I have an open mode and scrolled to the end of it. When closing this modal should I go directly to the beginning of the next modal?
Would it be the case to control the scroll internally in the modal div?