# How to make div modal scrolled to the top each time I open it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, simplemodal

I have built a modal by pure html, CSS, javascript.
It would pop-up as I click a button on the main page.

However, if I scroll down the model and close it, it would show the scrolled-down view as I reopen it. How can I make it always show the content at the top each time I open the model?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="button" id="btn"></div>

<div class="modal" id="mymdl">
    <div class="modal-content" id="mdl-con">
        <div class="modalwidth">
            <img class="image-title" id="img-ttl" src="./img/banner.png">
            <span class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="paragraph">
            Here is the main content.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    modal.style.display = "block";
});

var closeX = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
closeX.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

I have tried `window.scroll` method provided in the solution of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61990783/how-to-scroll-to-the-top-of-a-div-using-either-scrolltop-or-scrollto), but it didn't solve my problem.

I'm new to html, css, and javascript. Any idea would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding `modal.scrollTop = 0;` after you change the style to `display="block"`

Comment: @Chin.Udara Thank you for your advice! I found that `modal-content.scrollTop = 0;` works for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `element.scrollTop = 0` to scroll it to the top.

For example if `.paragraph` is what's getting scrolled, you can use something like this:

```js
const modal = document.getElementById("mymdl");

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    modal.style.display = "block";
});

var closeX = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
closeX.onclick = function() {
    modal.querySelector(".paragraph").scrollTop = 0; //scroll to the top
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.modal
{
  position: fixed;
}

.modal-content
{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.paragraph
{
  overflow: auto;
  height: 50vh;
  white-space: pre;
  text-align: center
}

.paragraph > div
{
  height: 120%;
}

.paragraph > span
{
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
}

.button,
.close
{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="button" id="btn">open modal</div>

<div class="modal" id="mymdl">
    <div class="modal-content" id="mdl-con">
        <div class="modalwidth">
            <img class="image-title" id="img-ttl" src="./img/banner.png">
            <span class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="paragraph">
        <div>Here is the main content.
scroll down</div><span>bottom</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this is the point! I've been trying `modal.scrollTop = 0`, but should change to `modal-content.scrollTop = 0`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way, rather than scroll to the top, bring the modal top to you.

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modal.style.top = window.pageYOffset + 10 + "px";
});
```

```js
const modal = document.querySelector('.modal')
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

for (let x = 0; x < btns.length; x++) {
  btns[x].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modal.style.top = window.pageYOffset + 10 + "px";
    console.log(window.pageYOffset, modal.style.top);
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  height: 1000px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 400px;
}

.modal {
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='modal'>Modal</div>

  <button class='btn'>click</button>
  <hr>
  <button class='btn'>click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice! However, this moves the position of my modal to top of the window, which is not quite what I mean. Sorry for the misleading I might had made. And I've found the solution!